# Composite or Unique Primary Key repititons

Tags: sql-server, database, primary-key, composite-primary-key

So i am working on creating a db, whereby i have the option of tableA or tableB. Please note that in the current concept InstanceID, slabID, and ChangeID are repeated in almost every table because only when combined with a table specific NO or key, can they uniquely identify each row.

> My concern is whether this composite primary key would be too big to impact performance or as i understand it would only give the table a logical sorting of the rows?

please see below for more details..

**TableA-Layering**
InstanceID(PK,FK)(Tinyint)---is 1 for the entire construction, unless new construction takes place
SlabID(PK,FK)(Tinyint)---ranges between 1-25, like tiles on the floor
ChangeID(PK,FK)(Tinyint)---would increment from 1 if the building is altered after completion
LayerSeq(PK)(Tinyint)--Foundation layer sequence ranging from 1-10
LayeringCode(PK)(Varchar(1))--Alphabetical code representing the material
.
.
*Other Layering variables*

Another option would be:
**TableB-Layering**
InstanceID(FK)(Tinyint)---is 1 for the entire construction, unless new construction takes place
SlabID(FK)(Tinyint)---ranges between 1-25, like tiles on the floor
ChangeID(FK)(Tinyint)---would increment from 1 if the building is altered after completion
**LayerID(PK)(Undecided)--which would be some combination of Instance,Slab,Change,Layerseq,code OR just a surrogate key with auto increments**
LayerSeq(Tinyint)--Foundation layer sequence ranging from 1-10
LayeringCode(Varchar(1))--Alphabetical code representing the material
.
.
*Other Layering variables*

Appreciate your help!

Comment: The performance impact here is not as cut and dry as it seems like it could be. Is this composite key also the clustered index? What are the datatypes? If they are ints then I would say this isn't an issue. If they are guids then you would get a different answer. There just isn't enough information posted at this point to provide a complete answer.

Comment: Yes, this composite key would be a clustered index key. Data Types for all of the above would be Tinyint. Except for LayerID and LayeringCode, which maybe a Varchar.

Comment: Again without more details it is difficult to speak fluently on your topic. I would warn you about premature optimization. This is the practice of making non-standard design decisions to solve a performance issue that does not yet exist. It is pure evil. If a composite key makes the most sense to your data then use that. IF you have performance problems down the road you should consider it then.